# Why does Node.js specify error.code for Errors but response.statusCode for Response?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, status

I am getting myself confused between `code` and `status` working with Node.js and Express.

When I create an `Error()` I do this for example:

```
const Err = new Error();
Err.message = "Login failed";
Err.code = 401;   // why is this not Err.statusCode or Err.status ?
throw(Err);
```

Returning that via Express ends up becoming:

```
catch (error) {
return res.status(error.code).send(error.message);
}
```

The Express.js [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) says that `res.status` *is an alias of  Node's response.statusCode*.

So why is the same code expressed in three different ways: `error.code`,  `response.statusCode` and `res.status`. Why isn't it consistently the same?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the `code` and `status` you're talking about refer to two different concepts.

1 - The `Error` class `code` property refers to a standard node.js concept and is not http-specific - just like the `Error` class iteself.

This is what node's documentation says about it:

*The error.code property is a string label that identifies the kind of error.*

If you want an `Error` object representing a http error to actually hold a http status information, then nothing prevents you from adding a dedicated custom `status` - or `statusCode` - property. A `httpError` value for the `code` property would probably be more fitting in this case since it refers to a higher-level concept than a more fine-grained http status.

2 - `response.statusCode` and `response.status` on the other hand are both http specific and relate to the http status of a `http.ServerResponse` object. The `http.ServerResponse` class is defined by node.js, and `res.status` is just a shorthand setter that is added by express for conveniency - and couldn't possibly be named after the same name as the property it serves as a setter for.

Comment: But in Node.js, `error.code` is not a string it is a number i.e. `Err.code = 401`.

Comment: As per the documentation, it should actually be a string. This is by convention. But there is no mechanism in place to prevent you from assigning a value of any type to it.